# Story about colony ships in suspended animation overtaken by newer, faster ships

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Does anyone know this science fiction story? It's about Earth sending a colonization ship to another world. The trip would take about 200 years so the people were put in suspended animation. 75 years later we developed the technology to travel faster than the speed of light so we used that technology to colonize the planet that was the destination of the people in suspended animation. That ship was left to complete its journey as scheduled, and those people finally arrived to find that the planet had been destroyed by nuclear war.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LightspeedLeapfrog

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53238/story-identification-sublight-starship-passed-by-ftl/53239#53239 (I don't think it's a dupe).

Comment: Possibly, but in Far Centaurus, the planet has not been ravaged by war.

Comment: Something similar happens in the game [Alien Legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Legacy), but it's not nuclear war that destroys the first colony.

Comment: Fwiw, this is the exact same question as [this one from a year later](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110558/short-story-where-humans-on-a-colony-ship-from-earth-are-overtaken-by-advanced-e), though it doesn't have an accepted answer yet. edit: and the same question as [this one from a year earlier](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53238/story-identification-sublight-starship-passed-by-ftl?noredirect=1&lq=1), although it doesn't have an accepted answer yet either.

Comment: Not the answer, but reminiscent:

In Larry Niven's Known Space series, One of the "Lazy Eight" series of sub-light hibernation "slowboats" (which one is a bit unclear -- sources are contradictory) missed its mark and continued on, it's path unknown until being discovered by the Outsiders, an alien race. The information is traded to humans, who by that point have lightspeed travel, having purchased that technology as well from the Outsiders, some years before.

See https://sites.google.com/site/knownspacetimeline/part-i-before-1964 , http://news.larryniven.net/concordance/main.asp?alpha=C

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like an episode of Star Trek: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Seed#Plot

Here's a couple videos:

and

“On stardate 3141.9, the Federation starship USS Enterprise finds the derelict SS Botany Bay floating in space. Botany Bay was launched from Earth in the 1990s. A landing party... beams over to the freighter. The landing party finds a cargo of 84 humans, 72 of whom are alive in suspended animation after **nearly 200 years**... In sickbay, the group's leader awakens and attacks McCoy but, impressed by McCoy's bravery, releases the doctor and introduces himself as ‘Khan' (Ricardo Montalbán). Lt. McGivers marvels over Khan, a living relic from the 20th century, her field of interest... Spock discovers that their guest is Khan Noonien Singh who, along with his people, are products of 20th-century selective breeding designed to create perfect humans. The genetic superhumans instead became warlords and conquered more than a third of the planet, sparking the Eugenics Wars, Earth's last major global conflict. Between eighty and ninety of the superhumans were unaccounted for at the end of the war;...
     “Taking advantage of McGivers' attraction towards him, Khan tells her he means to rule mankind again and needs her help to take over Enterprise. Reluctantly, she agrees, beaming Khan to Botany Bay, where he revives the rest of his superpeople. They return to Enterprise and assume control of the ship... Kirk and Spock vent anesthetic gas throughout the entire ship to disable Khan and his cohorts. Khan escapes the gas and heads to Engineering, where he attempts to destroy Enterprise, but Kirk confronts him and a brawl ensues. Though outmatched by Khan's superior strength, Kirk pulls an odd rod-like tool... from a wall and uses it as a club to knock the superman unconscious.
     “Kirk holds a hearing to decide the fate of Khan and his followers. The captain decides that they should be exiled to Ceti Alpha V, a harsh world that Kirk believes would be a perfect place for Khan to start his kingdom. Khan claims he is up to the challenge of taming the world and accepts Kirk's offer. Instead of a court-martial for Lt. McGivers, Kirk allows her to go into exile with Khan. Spock notes that ‘it would be interesting to see what Khan makes of Ceti Alpha V in 100 years.'"

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Seed#Plot

Answer (score 1):

There is a section of 'Quest for the Future' by (I think) A.E. Van Vogt that sounds like that.  The ship is travelling to Alpha Centauri but the planet is not destroyed when they arrive.

Comment: [*Quest for the Future*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?21899) by A. E. van Vogt is a fix-up novel based partly on his short story ["Far Centaurus"](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v32n05_1944-01_frankenscan#page/n67/mode/2up).

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that this is Far Centaurus by A. E. Van Vogt.

Comment: You need a description for why you think this. It adds more credibility. Maybe a synopsis.

Comment: In "Far Centaurus" the destination planets are thriving, not "destroyed by nuclear war".