# Short story involving colonists traveling to another planet going to andromeda after

Tags: story-identification, space-colonization

There's a short story where colonists went into cryo/stasis in order to survive a long journey towards another solar system in order to colonize a planet. However, in the time it took for them to travel from earth to their destination, technology overtook them and other humans managed to get their before them and colonize the planet.
The leaders of the colony ship then decided that they wanted a faster and better ship and then decided to go to the Andromeda galaxy to start a colony there.

I can't remember the name or author though :<

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154911/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Is this a repeat of another question? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110558/short-story-where-humans-on-a-colony-ship-from-earth-are-overtaken-by-advanced-e

Comment: Nope, not at all. This short story has no humans evolving into something different, no mention of conscious spacecraft, and, at the last it's described going to a distant solar system. At the end of mine they really want to go to Andromeda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"[The Shoulders of Giants](http://www.sfwriter.com/stshould.htm)" by Robert J. Sawyer. Quoting from the TV Tropes page [Lightspeed Leapfrog](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LightspeedLeapfrog):

> The colonists arrive in a sleeper ship at about 1% of the speed of light. and find out their intended planet is already colonized and thriving. Fortunately, they manage to convince the colony to give them a relativistic ship to carry sleepers to head for the Andromeda galaxy.