# Short sci-fi story about a group of people space travelling to a distant planet, overtaken by a second group who left after them but were faster

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-exploration

Does anyone know this short story I read many years ago? It's about a group of people who decided to get to a distant planet on a spaceship that isn't very advanced. Some time after they started their trip, new technology got developed that allows space travel at a much faster speed. A second group of people who set out for the same destination end up arriving a lot earlier than the first group of people.

I think this would be a good story to introduce my kids to space travel but couldn't remember the name of the book.

Answer (score 5):

This is a common theme, but as indicated by the close voters it may be a duplicate of [Sublight Starship “passed” by FTL](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53238/sublight-starship-passed-by-ftl). Here is part of user14111's not-yet-accepted answer, identifying the title as **"Far Centaurus"**.

> **I'm a huge fan of SF from the golden age of SF, so this could be a fairly old book. It was a story about a "generation" starship or sublight starship.**
>
> It's "Golden Age" all right (Astounding Science Fiction, January 1944, available at the Internet Archive) but it's not a book, it's a short story: "Far Centaurus" by A. E. van Vogt.
>
> **It was a story about a "generation" starship or sublight starship.**
>
> It was a sublight starship (500 years from Sol to Alpha Centauri) but not a generation ship, it was a sleeper ship. The crew were awakened from suspended animation at long intervals, one at a time...

Comment: This looks like the one I read 20 years ago. Thanks!

Comment: @Cheng You can "accept" the answer to mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark on the left :-)