# 60s (or earlier) SF short story with FTL Travel using electron psychology aka addiclenendar technology

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ftl-drive

My question is about an old SF short story from a compendium of them which I had as a child back in 1965/1966.

Story is about a sleeper ship traveling to a nearby star with two guys on board who split shifts being conscious and in hibernation. As they approach the end of their journey a starship from Earth approaches them, it is FTL capable utilizing newly-discovered technology of electron psychology, or "addiclenendar", to achieve FTL travel. For some reason I thought it was Van Vogt, but haven't been able to find a story of his that matches this storyline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sublight Starship "passed" by FTL](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53238/sublight-starship-passed-by-ftl)

Comment: Similar questions have been asked several times - the answer is probably *Far Centaurus* by A.E. van Vogt.

Comment: @LAK Probably. And linking to it (or posting an answer) is fine, but not yet flagging it as dupe, as we don't yet have acceptances, which [per consensus on Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028) are mandatory before dupe-closing. Voted to leave open

Comment: Maybe. The cincher woud be a mention of using "electron psychology" tech for the FTL drive. For some reason that has stuck with me all these years. I'll have to try to find the story.

Answer (score 15):

This is the story ["Far Centarus"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41417) by A.E. van Vogt as suggested by the comment.

If you check out [page 81 of the story](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v32n05_1944-01_frankenscan#page/n79/mode/2up) in the January 1944 issue of Astounding Science Fiction, you'll find the term "adeledicnander electronic psychology" used for the technology which powers their FTL drive, which pretty much conclusively matches what you remember.

Comment: ...and this would definitely make it a duplicate of the older question.